ReactNative map view, markers won't display without moving the map after load
I have a Functional Component in my React Native app that when loaded, I want to check for user location permissions, and then load a map based on the users location. When that location is loaded I make a Google Maps API call to search for nearby stores and display markers in the MapView.
The issue is, the API call is being made when the map renders, but no markers are being displayed until the map is moved slightly. From my console.logs the API call is being made when the view first loads and I do see results come back and get set to the state object.
My code is below, I'm relatively new to React-Native, any input would be welcome!
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Platform, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import MapView, { Marker, Region } from 'react-native-maps';
import { request, PERMISSIONS } from 'react-native-permissions';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

interface StoreFinderState {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  latitudeDelta: number;
  longitudeDelta: number;
}

const StoreFinderView: React.FC = () => {
  const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState<StoreFinderState>({
    // Start with default location
    latitude: 41.88015,
    longitude: -87.63515,
    latitudeDelta: 0.05,
    longitudeDelta: 0.05,
  });

  const [stores, setStores] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const getLocation = useCallback(() => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        console.log(position);
        setMapRegion({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.05,
          longitudeDelta: 0.05,
        });
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.code, error.message);
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
      const status = await request(
        Platform.OS === 'ios' ? PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE : PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
      );
      if (status === 'granted') {
        getLocation();
      }
    };

    requestLocationPermission();
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    searchStores(mapRegion);
  }, [mapRegion]);

  const searchStores = useCallback(
    debounce(async (region: Region) => {
      try {
        console.log('Search for stores');
        const response = await fetch(
          'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?' +
            `keyword=KEYWORD_SEARCH&location=${region.latitude}%2C${region.longitude}&radius=1500` +
            '&type=store&key=API_KEY',
          {
            method: 'GET',
          }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data.results.length);
        setStores(data.results);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }, 500),
    []
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.container}
        region={mapRegion}
        onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => {setMapRegion(region)}}
      >
        {stores.map((store: any) => (
          <Marker
            key={store.place_id}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: store.geometry.location.lat,
              longitude: store.geometry.location.lng,
            }}
            title={store.name}
            description={store.vicinity}
          />
        ))}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default StoreFinderView;



Maybe it's a thing about the useEffects? Have you tried passing mapRegion to useEffect that is responsible for getting user's permission?
I have a similliar functionality, but i just pass the params of a Region I want to show to a user on the map. Here's the code, maybe You can get something out of it for Yourself.
Map.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker, Region } from 'react-native-maps';
import pinIcon from '../assets/icons/pinicon.png';

// Define the expected type for postLocation prop
type PostLocation = {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
};

const Map = ({ postLocation }: { postLocation: PostLocation }) => {
  const { latitude, longitude } = postLocation;

  if (!latitude || !longitude) {
    return (
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <Text>Location data not available.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  const region: Region = {
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
  };

  return (
    <MapView
      style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      region={region} // Use region to dynamically update the map
      showsUserLocation={false}
    >
      <Marker
        coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }}
        title="Animal Location"
        image={pinIcon}
      />
    </MapView>
  );
};

export default Map;

MapViewScreen.js
 const { postData } = useLocalSearchParams();
  const post = JSON.parse(postData); // Parse post data from string

  // Define post location with latitude and longitude parsed as numbers
  const postLocation = {
    latitude: parseFloat(post.latitude),
    longitude: parseFloat(post.longitude),
  };

<Map postLocation={postLocation} />

Also, just thinking out loud, untill you find a proper solution, if moving a map slightly makes it refresh, maybe you can make it move slightly for example 0,0001 lat after it should render, so its unseeable for the user, but it refreshes the markers? Goodluck
